# Clojure Loop Function Only Returns Nil

Tags: clojure

The function below splits the *text* variable into a sequence of characters that is *steps* long. The only problem is I can't figure out how to return the resulting list, which I need to compute its Shannon entropy for several values of *step*.

```
(defn split-text [text step]

  (loop [i 0 result []]
    (when (<= (+ i step) (count text))
      (recur (+ i step)
             (conj result (subs text i (+ i step)))))))
```

Comment: as the answer below says, you should return result in a false condition branch. You can also do something like this, to reduce code complexity: `(defn split-text [text step]
  (map (partial apply str) (partition step text)))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result from the loop:

```
(defn split-text [text step]
  (loop [i 0 result []]
    (if (> (+ i step) (count text))
      result  ;; <== here
      (recur (+ i step)
             (conj result (subs text i (+ i step)))))))
```

Also, the last chunk will be lost if it's less than `step` characters long. If you want to keep it:

```
(defn split-text [text step]
  (loop [tail text result []]
    (if (empty? tail)
      result
      (let [len (min step (count tail))]
        (recur (subs tail len)
               (conj result (subs tail 0 len)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.